# Call other rest service after pass by the gateway - Implementation

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, gateway

Here we use Spring Cloud Gateway , Eureka Server and some microservices.

When the user (frontend) call a rest service he needs to call the gateway then the gateway do the loadbalance and returns the result for the user. (OK)

Our problem is when this rest service call other rest service after pass by the gateway.

When this fact occur we call the gateway again to do this call, is it ok to do? Or the best practice would be use a client loadbalance to do this request direct on the service dont using the gateway again.

Anyone could help me about this doubt?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It depends. If you are ok with the extra network hop, it allows you to centrally manage API access and security. VMware has a commercial product built on gateway that does just that. If you don't want the extra hop, use client-side load balancing. There's no best practice, only requirements :-).

Comment: Each of your microservices act as a Eureka client and register its self to it on startup so the availiblity and load balanced can be placed. They register themselves with the component names and when you invoke a inter component communication via Feign or something you invoke it via application name which goes to Eureka and gets routed from there to the other component.